# Spark session initializes after calling sc.parallelize

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

After both Spark context and session are initialized, calling sparkContext.parallelize(config.platforms), where config.platforms is a list:

```
platforms = sc.parallelize(config.platforms)
```

triggers creation of a new session and corresponding message 'Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041'. Why does it happen?

[image]

**Update:**: I'm using PyCharm to run pyspark code. Problem stays for Run, Debug modes

Comment: please add more details. screen-shot, are you doing this in spark-shell or via spark-submit. any necessary code.

Comment: What is config.platforms?

Comment: List. Does it matter?